# Conversion from String to Char in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, type-conversion

I am taking input from user in visual c++ through the following code

```
Console::WriteLine("Select the Cache Size.\n a. 1 Kb \n b. 2 Kb \n c. 4 Kb \n d. 8 Kb\n");
    String^ CACHE_SIZEoption = Console::ReadLine();
    Char wh= Char(CACHE_SIZEoption);

    switch(wh)
    {case 'a':
    break;

    case 'b':
    break;

    case 'c':
     break;

    case 'd':
    break;
    }
```

In this the conversion from String to Char is giving errors..

```
 error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'System::String ^' to 'wchar_t'
```

Comment: What does `String^` mean?  It's not C++ for sure...

Comment: @trojanfoe It's C++/CLI, a Microsoft language based on C++ and integrated into the Common Language Infrastructure.

Comment: @Angew Yeah, I had a fair idea; just my way of saying "sort your tags out" :)

Comment: Please tell me hoe the conversion should take place... Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unrealistic to expect to be able to convert a string into a character. A string can contain 0, 1 or more characters. Which character do you want?

If you want the first character, use `CACHE_SIZEoption[0]`, after having checked that the string is not empty.

In your case you probably want to add a check that the string's length is exactly 1 because otherwise that means the user's input is invalid. Check `CACHE_SIZEoption->Length`.

Comment: I want to use the switch statement, and switch only holds char.. Moreover i want to check if user selected the option a, or b or c

Comment: Yes, I understand all that. Is there a part of my answer that you don't understand?

Comment: Why would it not be applicable?

Comment: That's a completely and utterly different question, on a different subject altogether. I reverted your edit because it makes the existing answers to your original question invalid. If you want help with the other question, ask a new question. The answer lies in the fact that you are using #define rather than setting a variable. The thing about #define is that it is processed at compile time by the pre-processor. So it's absolutely not what you want. You need to use a variable instead rather than a macro.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
Char wh= CACHE_SIZEoption[0];
```

or

```
Char wh= CACHE_SIZEoption->ToChar();
```

Found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335877%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: String does not have a `ToChar()` method

Comment: I have used the second option, the error is " left of '.ToChar' must have class/struct/union"

Comment: While I'm still confused what I don't understand about the documentation of String, there is yet one option left.

Comment: You could for example write `IConvertible^ CACHE_SIZEoption_cvt = CACHE_SIZEoption; CACHE_SIZEoption_cvt->ToChar();` but that's much messier than just subscripting.